# Updating signature of all users in my Google domain account

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

Hi am trying to build an app to standardized signatures of all users in my google domain.

For that I have tried with following Google APIs in apis explorer
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.settings.sendAs.patch
and pass other user's Id and email with custom signature but it's giving me following error

REQUEST

```
<pre>
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/[21_DIGIT_USER_ID]/settings/sendAs/[SOME_OTHER_USER@DOMAIN.COM]?fields=signature&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "signature": "my custom signature"
}
</pre>
```

RESPONSE

```
<pre>
403 Forbidden
- Show headers -
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Delegation denied for myemailid@mydomain.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Delegation denied for myemailid@mydomain.com"
 }
}
</pre>
```

Although I have delegated admin access and  I am able to change my user's signature by passing me in userId field and email id in sendAsEmail.
What's the use of userId field if an delegated admin can't change other user's signature.

Comment: How have you done delegation?   I dont think you are going to be able to delegate though APis exploerer your going to have to do this with your own code and a service account.

Comment: I have tried with admin access also as I check directory api for my users role . It's showing isAdmin=true

Comment: I have delegated service account which now I am using for changing signature , but it's raising error "The API returned an error: Error: Bad Request"

Comment: I am trying to do the exact same thing. How did you delegate access?